# Logging important info in WebAPI 2 using Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, serilog

Just started working with Serilog, Its quite nice but I am a bit confused.

In case of errors in my Controller's actions, I'd like to log as much **useful** information as possible from the request (headers, parameters, etc).

What would be the best way to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could look at using the [Enrichment](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Enrichment) feature

As per the documentation from the link, you would construct your logger similar to

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
.Enrich.WithThreadId()
.WriteTo.Console()
.CreateLogger();
```

"All events written through log will carry a property ThreadId with the id of the managed thread that wrote them. (By convention, any .WithXyz() methods on Enrich create properties named Xyz.)"

An example on Github is [SerilogWeb.Classic](https://github.com/serilog-web/classic). It provides a number of enrichers to capture certain information from the Request, e.g.

```
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
.WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
.Enrich.With<HttpRequestIdEnricher>()
.Enrich.With<UserNameEnricher>()
.CreateLogger();
```

You could follow a similar apporach, creating an enricher that captures the information you always want to output in your logs, then initialising your logger using the enricher.

Comment: `SerilogWeb.Classic.WebApi` adds some more WebAPI info as well, I think: https://github.com/serilog-web/classic-webapi